# hive compaction using insert overwrite partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hql

Trying to address the small files problem by compacting the files under hive partitions by Insert overwrite partition command in hadoop.

**Query :**

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.max.split.size=256000000;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000;


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tbl1 PARTITION (year=2016, month=03, day=11) 
SELECT col1,col2,col3  from tbl1  
WHERE year=2016 and  month=03 and  day=11;
```

**Input Files:**

For testing purpose I have three files under the hive partition (2016/03/11) in HDFS with the size of 40 MB each.

> 2016/03/11/file1.csv
>
> 2016/03/11/file2.csv
>
> 2016/03/11/file3.csv

Example my block size is 128 , So I would like to create only one output files. But I am getting 3 different compressed files.

Please help me to get the hive configuration to restrict the output file size. If I am not using the compression I am getting the single file.

Hive Version : 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's interesting that you are still getting 3 files when specifying the partition when using compression so you may want to look into dynamic partitioning or ditch the partitioning and focus on the number of mappers and reducers being created by your job. If your files are small I could see how you would want them all in one file on your target, but then I would also question the need for compression on them.

The number of files created in your target is directly tied to the number of reducers or mappers. If the SQL you write needs to reduce then the number of files created will be the same as the number of reducers used in the job. This can be controlled by setting the number of reducers used in the job.

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks = 1;
```

In your example SQL there most likely wouldn't be any reducers used, so the number of files in the target is equal to the number of mappers used which is equal to the number of files in the source. It isn't as easy to control the number of output files on a map only job but there are a number of configuration settings that can be tried.

Setting to combine small input files so fewer mappers are spawned, the default is false.

```
set hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat = true;
```

Try setting a threshold in bytes for the input files, anything under this threshold would try to be converted to a map join which can affect the number of output files.

```
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize = 25000000;
```

As for the compression I would play with changing the type of compression being used just to see if that makes any difference in your output.

```
set hive.exec.orc.default.compress = gzip, snappy, etc...
```

Comment: #Salmonerd , As you said there is no reducer are running because its map only job,  I am basically trying to address small files issue by combining into bigger files using insert overwrite in hive partition. Let me try the configuration suggested by you and I will get back.

Comment: Works as expected. Created only single file out of multiple small files.

Comment: Awesome, which settings did you implement?

Comment: `SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;

SET mapred.max.split.size=256000000;

set hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat = true;

set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize = 25000000;

SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;

SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000;

set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000;

set hive.merge.mapredfiles=false;

set hive.merge.mapfiles =true;`

Comment: Hii @WilliamR, I am also using this same method to address the small files issue. I used the `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause to make sure files of one partition goes into one reducer (with this I did have to use any of the above settings you have mentioned) . But now I have a problem, what if my table does not have any partition column, then in that case how can I make reducer count 1. Tried these settings but nothing seemed to work. Please help!!

Comment: You mean you don’t store data under partitioned directory ? In that do you always overwrite entire partition every time ??

Comment: @WilliamR .. Yes, there is no partitioned directory... Just inside the main table directory I have many files which I want to merge. I don't overwrite, just append new data in that.

Comment: @Hemakshi sachdev Have you tried mapred.reduce.task=1 (syntax slightly change based on Hadoop version) if this is not working please share exact set commands which you using.